# Type conversion with generics and inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I present you the problem, The problem comes from a `NullReferenceException`, due to the fact that when I convert my DofusClient object to TClient via the As operator that returns to me null(bad cast reason). I do not see why the compiler denies me this cast while TClient when calling my class is an object of the type `AuthClient` that inherits `DofusClient`, then I added it in the where clause of my class Frame Manager.

```
public class FrameManager<TClient> : IFrameManager where TClient : DofusClient
   {
       private readonly ImmutableDictionary<int, Action<TClient, IDofusMessage>> m_frames;
       private IContextHandler m_threading;

       public FrameManager(ImmutableDictionary<int, Action<TClient, IDofusMessage>> frames,
           IContextHandler threading)
       {
           this.m_frames = frames;
           this.m_threading = threading;
       }

       public void Execute<TMessage>(DofusClient client, TMessage message) where TMessage : IDofusMessage
       {
           if (!m_frames.TryGetValue(message.ProtocolId, out var method))
               Logger.Instance.Log(LogLevel.Warn, "NETWORK-FRAME", $"Message id {message.ProtocolId} exists but isn't listed on frames.");
           else
           {
               Logger.Instance.Log(LogLevel.Info, "NETWORK-FRAME", $"Message Id {message.ProtocolId} has been parsed and treated.");

               m_threading.ExecuteInContext(() => method(client as TClient, message));
           }
       }
   }

public class FrameBuilder<TClient>
   {
       private readonly ImmutableDictionary<int, Action<TClient, IDofusMessage>>.Builder m_frames;

       public FrameBuilder()
       { this.m_frames = ImmutableDictionary.CreateBuilder<int, Action<TClient, IDofusMessage>>(); }


       public FrameBuilder<TClient> RegisterFrame<TFrame>() where TFrame : IFrame, new()
       {
           IFrame frame = new TFrame();
           Action<TClient, IDofusMessage> del;
           MessageHandlerAttribute attribute;
           IEnumerable<MethodInfo> methods = frame.GetType()
                                                   .GetMethods()
                                                   .Where(x => (x.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(MessageHandlerAttribute))
                                                   as MessageHandlerAttribute) != null);
           foreach (MethodInfo method in methods)
           {
               attribute = (MessageHandlerAttribute)method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(MessageHandlerAttribute));

               del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<TClient, IDofusMessage>), null, method)
                     as Action<TClient, IDofusMessage>;

               m_frames.Add(attribute.MessageId, del);

           }

           Logger.Instance.Log(LogLevel.Debug, $"FRAME-BUILDER",
               $"{ methods.Count()} methods handled from {typeof(TFrame).Name}.");

           return this;
       }

       public ImmutableDictionary<int, Action<TClient, IDofusMessage>> Build()
       { return m_frames.ToImmutable(); }
   }


public class FrameDispatcher
   {
       private readonly ImmutableDictionary<int, Func<IDofusMessage>> m_messageProvider;
       private readonly IFrameManager m_frameManager;

       public FrameDispatcher(ImmutableDictionary<int, Func<IDofusMessage>> messageProvider, IFrameManager frameManager)
       {
           this.m_messageProvider = messageProvider;
           this.m_frameManager = frameManager;
       }

       public void Dispatch(DofusClient client, Frame<DofusMetadata> frame)
       {
           int key = frame.Metadata.MessageId;

           if (!m_messageProvider.TryGetValue(key, out var msgCtor))
               Logger.Instance.Log(LogLevel.Warn,"[NETWORK]", $"The message received isn't in the protocol : {key}.");
           else
           {
               IDofusMessage message = msgCtor();
               var reader = new DofusReader(frame.Payload);

               message.Deserialize(reader);
               m_frameManager.Execute(client, message);
           }

       }

    public class IdentificationFrame : IFrame
    {
        [MessageHandler(IdentificationMessage.NetworkId)]
        public void HandleIdentificationMessage(AuthClient client, IDofusMessage msg)
        {
            var message = msg as IdentificationMessage;
            /*Here AuthClient is null*/
           _= client.SendMessageAsync(new IdentificationSuccessMessage()
                .InitIdentificationSuccessMessage("test", "null", 1, 0, new WrappedBool(false), "lol", 12222, 222, 000222
                , new WrappedBool(false), 0));
        }

    }
```

Of course it would be easier to directly put the type AuthClient in Frame Builder.cs and Frame Manager.Cs but the project is separated into several assemblies where AuthClient is not in the assembly of other classes. In addition FrameBuilder / FrameManager will be reused for another type of data so I do not prefer to repeat myself in the code.

Thanks for reading and have a nice day.

Comment: Point of note: using the correct casting operator for your situation will make your code easier to debug. The `as` operator returns `null` if the cast cannot be made, meaning it's difficult to know if it was a bad cast, or that the value was `null` in the first place. Always prefer the [cast operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#cast-operator-) unless you have a good reason to use `as`.

Comment: It's most likely that `client` is null before it is passed to `Execute`. Since we can't see where it is created, fix your casting as above, and the error should become clearer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, the client is not null when it is passed to the Execute method when debugging, I see the instance in the debugger view.

Comment: OK - so what is the type of `TClient` when you debug? Is `TClient` a different subtype of `DofusClient`?

Comment: TClient is a AuthClient object and AuthClient is a subtype of DofusClient but `TClient childClient = client as TClient;` return null. Maybe it's because FrameManager and AuthClient are not in the same project (assembly) ? I really have no idea ..

Comment: To be clear, `TClient` is _not_ an object. It's a type. If the `client` argument is an `AuthClient` but the `TClient` type argument is `SomethingElseClient`, then it won't be castable. That's the only other situation I can think of.

Comment: If I use direct cast with (), I have an InvalidCastException : 'Unable to cast object of type 'Renaissance.Abstract.Network.DofusClient' to type 'Renaissance.Auth.Networking.AuthClient'.' So the cast is not possible here because TClient is a type of AuthClient and it's a downcasting ?

Comment: Yep, so `TClient` is the subclass, but `client` is an instance of the base class.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain myself, have nice day.